# Get Pyramid View callable by it's path (request context)

Tags: python, url, pyramid

I am making an app that would translate websocket messages to AJAX requests to the server. Mainly the decision is based on the fact that Pyramid already has a good URL dispatch system and it would be stupid not to use it.

The question is if there is an easy way to dispatch a URL in Pyramid (possibly an instanced Request object) to it's according view callable and *get* the view callable? Or at least get the output of the view callable related to the request?

I have tried the script from "prequest.py" which basically emulates a whole HTTP client and gives you the response (I have still not managed to get it work, but a look through the sources makes sense anyway) and I wouldn't like to do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do it using Router.invoke_subrequest in the latest version of Pyramid (1.4a1).

This enables all the features related to routing. URL dispatch, parameter passing, tweens.

You can read about it here: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.invoke_subrequest

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse the code from the `pview` command to turn a path into a view reference:

```
from pyramid.scripts.pviews import PViewsCommand

pvcomm = PViewsCommand([])
view = pvcomm._find_view(path, request.registry)
```

The actual code to do this is a little involved, but the `PViewsCommand` does it all for us already.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work through `pshell`, I get `TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`. It looks like the `PViewsCommand.__init__` needs an `argv`

Comment: @jamesc: Indeed; an empty list suffices.