# Given a URL how to find a view callable in pyramid?

Tags: python, testing, pyramid

I want to write unit test, that proves that correct url will resolve to my view callable.
In this question [Get Pyramid View callable by it's path (request context)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707400/get-pyramid-view-callable-by-its-path-request-context) I found the way to do it, but my test fails, probably that is because `self.testing.scan()` hasn't been run?

How can I reliably test that application will find correct view callable?

```
import unittest

from pyramid import testing


class ViewTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.config = testing.setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        testing.tearDown()

    # This one fails
    def test_root_path_points_to_correct_view_callable(self):
        from ..views import my_view
        from pyramid.scripts.pviews import PViewsCommand
        views_command = PViewsCommand([])

        view = views_command._find_view(testing.DummyRequest(path='/'))

        assert my_view is view

    # This one passes
    def test_my_view(self):
        from ..views import my_view
        request = testing.DummyRequest()
        info = my_view(request)
        self.assertEqual(info['project'], 'my_project')
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `self.config.scan('module name')`?